# Rewrite instead of append to XML file

Tags: java, xml

I am using the code below in order to write to a XML file, but every time I run this function, the info gets appended and not rewritten in the XML file.

What should I change in order to rewrite the file and not append the info every time?

Here is the function:

```
public void write2file(LinkedList<Customer> customers, File ff) {
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(ff);
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

        // Root Element
        Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();

        for (Customer i : customers) {
            // server elements
            Element new_marker = document.createElement("Marker");
            rootElement.appendChild(new_marker);

            Element name = document.createElement("title");
            name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.getTitle()));
            new_marker.appendChild(name);

            Element loc = document.createElement("site_location");
            loc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.getLocation()));
            new_marker.appendChild(loc);

            Element latitude = document.createElement("latitude");
            latitude.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.getLatitude()));
            new_marker.appendChild(latitude);

            Element longitude = document.createElement("longitude");
            longitude.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.getLongitude()));
            new_marker.appendChild(longitude);

            Element status = document.createElement("status");
            status.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.getStatus()));
            new_marker.appendChild(status);

            root.appendChild(new_marker);
        }

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ff);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } 
    catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();}
    catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a new File object in the "new StreamResult(ff)" and then delete the old file? It's not exactly what you want but..

Comment: Yea i did, but for some reason it adds only the last node from the linked list.

Comment: Not sure if it can have something to do with the problem but you are appending the new_maker object twice inside the for loop. One to the "root" object and then again to the "rootElement" object, but they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of giving file directly as argument of StreamResult, try to give FileOutputStream, which can take constructor parameter whether to append or not.

```
new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(ff, false));
```

Answer (score 1):

simply delete file before writting new data, new one will be created automatically

```
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
ff.delete();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ff);
```

Comment: if(ff.exists()){
         ff.delete();}
         StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ff);

This is what i did but i get an exception that says:
java.io.FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to erase the contents of your file before you write it out, either creating a new file that happens to have the same name, or deleting the file and creating a new one.

Comment: I guess i will just delete it.